# Did the Mayans believe the Earth was flat?

Tags: astronomy

Many places (e.g., [here](http://www.historymuseum.ca/cmc/exhibitions/civil/maya/mmc03eng.shtml)) state that the Mayans thought the Earth was flat.

At the same time, Mayan astronomical knowledge is impressive. They made accurate computations of the length of a solar year and of planets like Venus. Is it really possible, with such advanced knowledge of astronomy, that Mayans believed the Earth was flat?

Comment: With up to 2 million people, it seems likely that the one culture contained multitudes of opinions and beliefs...

Comment: @Oddthinking Sheer number of people doesn't mean a multitude of beliefs. Because it has 350m people doesn't mean the modern US contains a huge multitude of opinions on whether the Earth is flat or round.

Comment: @DJClayworth: Ha! Good point. I just get my guard up when people say "Australian Aborigines believe that..." or "Jews believe that...", and I am worried this might revolve around a similar false assumption.

Answer (score 2):

The anthropological consensus does appear to be that the Mayans believed the earth was flat - at least as a generalization. Sifting reliable sources from the hundreds of pages of woo is extremely difficult, but here are some relatively good references I have found:

- [The Canadian Museum of History](http://www.historymuseum.ca/cmc/exhibitions/civil/maya/mmc03eng.shtml)
- [Civilizations textbook](https://books.google.ca/books?id=e8ppAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA11&lpg=PA11&dq=mayans%20believed%20earth%20was%20flat%20academic&source=bl&ots=c6KFeD8Ek_&sig=X91ON54Ook2-3RXEypKP8bWL3Yw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiWyfzG9M3MAhXD44MKHdX5B6oQ6AEIazAQ#v=onepage&q=mayans%20believed%20earth%20was%20flat%20academic&f=false) (for grades 5-8 but written by a qualified researcher)
- [Introduction to Earth Science](https://books.google.ca/books?id=pItrLtkeW2QC&pg=PA23&lpg=PA23&dq=mayans%20believed%20earth%20was%20flat%20academic&source=bl&ots=jVcEzU4jUl&sig=a34iTD7ejg_GmgzUFBCc5f4sZCI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwif6MPh9c3MAhWj5IMKHa_vA6M4ChDoAQgdMAE#v=onepage&q=mayans%20believed%20earth%20was%20flat%20academic&f=false)

I'm aware that the first link is in the question, but since it's a reference from a reliable source it deserves to be included.

Comment: I've upvoted, but it would be nice to see something more primary than a textbook. Textbooks have been wrong before.

Comment: [Seafaring ancients usually figured out the world was not flat](http://history.stackexchange.com/a/11353/2732), and the ancient Mayans were seafarers.